# Mapping an object to the resource with RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm learning RestKit and would like to POST a payload using the object mapper. I'm using registerMapping: but this creates the mapping on a root key. Is there a way to map the object to the resource instead? My mapping code looks like this:

```
[self.objectManager.router routeClass:[Session class] toResourcePath:@"/sessions" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[self.objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:[Session mappingForObjectStore:self.objectManager.objectStore] 
                                    withRootKeyPath:@""];

[self.objectManager postObject:session usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.resourcePath = @"/sessions";
    loader.delegate = self;

}];
```

which creates a payload like this:

> {
>   "" : {data:"stuff"}
>   }

but I'm after a payload like this:

> {
>   data:"stuff"
>   }

What's The RestKit Way here?

Answer (score 0):

Blake pointed me to using a different API that I had overlooked. So I replaced registerMapping with:

```
[self.objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:[Session mappingForObjectStore:self.objectManager.objectStore]
                              forResourcePathPattern:@"/sessions"];
[self.objectManager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[[Session mappingForObjectStore:self.objectManager.objectStore] inverseMapping]
                                                   forClass:[Session class]];
```

Three cheers!